# Database Exception: Command `pg_restore` not found with odoo9

Tags: postgresql, odoo-9

While,Trying to restore database form database manager then getting this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case, I able to solve this issue just adding a config setting in openerp-server.conf

```
file pg_path=C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin
```

Comment: Had the same problem with odoo12 and that worked just fine for me too.